# How to backup Windows 10 to network share using encryption?

Tags: windows-10, backup, encryption

There is an SMB network share on a FreeNAS server.

I would like to create regular, scheduled backups of my Windows 10 laptop to this smb share, but in an encrypted way such that the FreeNAS admin has no way of accessing the contents of the backup.

1. Is there a robust way to achieve this with Windows 10 (Pro) native tools alone?
2. If not, what freeware tools can enable me to do this?

Comment: It's already stated in the original question (it's Windows 10 Pro)

Comment: Have you looked into using EFS?  This would protect your personal files.  Most Third-party disk imaging programs support encrypted backup images.  Likewise using BitLocker will protect your personal files also.

Comment: @Ramhound how would I use that to create encrypted backups on a network share?

Comment: EFS and BitLocker backups wouldn’t be encrypted themselves but the data contained within them would be.  What you use to create the backups is really important

Comment: @Ramhound well that's kinda my question here

Comment: I am trying to get you describe what method you will be using to backup your system.  What method you plan on using will determine if encryption will be possible or not.  The built-in tool, `Windows Backup`, is limited in it's functionality.  It wasn't one hundred percent clear if you want both your backup solution and encryption solution to be limited to built-in tools or just the encryption solution.  Windows Backup isn't the most feature rich solution, I certainly wouldn't trust it, for my system backups.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use the built in Windows backup to create a backup and export it to your hard drive. There appears to be a cmd command called cipher.exe which would let you encrypt files. I do not have any experience with cipher.exe so I recommend looking into before using it. If you want to step away from the realm of native tools you can use something like ssh to encrypt your backup you created.

That said I would recommend Veracrypt as a solution to backup and encrypt your laptop. Veracrypt is an open source encryption software based on the now abandoned truecrypt. It fixes all of the vulnerabilities that were found during the [Truecrypt audit](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2015/04/02/truecrypt-report/). Veracrypt itself has also been [audited](https://blog.quarkslab.com/security-assessment-of-veracrypt-fixes-and-evolutions-from-truecrypt.html) and the issues found during the audit was fixed in 1.19.

You can get started with their beginner tutorial here:
https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Beginner%27s%20Tutorial.html

There are other free backup solutions you can look into but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: It seems for this I would need a third, local storage location to first create the backup on and then to copy the encypted container to the nas. I'd prefere if there was something that can automatically run on a regular schedule and does not require an additional third storage locaiton.

Comment: You wouldn't need a third local storage if I am understanding your question correctly. You would encrypt locally and have the read only copy on the NAS. You can continue to use the OS while it's encrypted and even after it's encrypted. When you login to your laptop it will prompt for a password. https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Encryption.html

Alternatively if you don't want to risk that you can do the first step I mentioned and only encrypt the windows backup that is generated by windows.

Comment: i have a 1B laptop of which currently about 700GB are in use, so I don't have locally enough space to store a full backup

Comment: I see, so yo would have to encrypt directly to the share itself. There's a few issue with VeraCrypt in regards to saving to network drives (NAS or not). The main one being that losing connection to the network drive during a write operation can cause corruptions and that the traffic itself is not encrypted (Though your NAS probably already encrypts the traffic).

Do you need a full backup or is there select files you need to backup.

Comment: I don't mind traffic itself not being encrypted, but since I'm connected through wifi, the connection may get interrupted at any moment

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't think there is a good solution since any backup solution going through wifi is subject to potential corruption from losing connection. Does it need to be a full backup or are there select files that need to be encrypted?

Comment: I'd like to have a full backup. I'm sure there are ways of doing it. Dropbox for example also never corrupts any files even if connection is switched on and off randomly

Comment: AFAIK dropbox encrypts the data at rest and then sends(syncs) it to the dropbox server and it's still subject to the same issue of corruption (though it's much less likely). The issue of corruption comes from the encryption being part of transit. There is probably a solution but I am currently unaware of it and hopefully another user responds with the answer.